# After upgrading target sdk version to 33(android 13), Flutter app is installing but not launching automatically

Tags: android, android-api-levels, android-13, targetsdkversion, flutter-upgrade

I have changed targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion to 33,and minSdkVersion is 23 in build.gradle file and in AndroidManifest.xml, updated permissions like this

[image: AndroidManifest.xml]

When I do flutter run, App is installing in emulator(api level 33) and apk also generating but not launching (opening) automatically.

If I open manually by clicking on it,then app is opening.
Flutter run is stucking at Installing `build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...`,

I have attached the image below.

[image: screenshoot]

Comment: The same here. The app is not able to open from a link as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add the next line to `android/app/src/AndroidManifest.xml`

`<action android:name="android.intent.action.RUN"/>`

In this part:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.RUN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

I'm ussing flutter 1.22 and I changed the targetSdkVersion 28 to `targetSdkVersion 33`. This is the only fix that worked for me, for auto launching the app.

Remember to use `flutter run -v` in console to see what is happening.

In my case, the error was:

```
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {} does not exist.
```